# Missing @ConditionalBean on StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration.stormpathApplicationResolver

Tags: spring-boot, stormpath

While trying to add Stormpath to my existing Spring-Boot application, I have the following error on startup.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on     com.stormpath.spring.boot.autoconfigure.StormpathWebMvcAutoConfiguration.stormpathApplicationResolver
```

...

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotations must specify at least one bean (type, name or annotation)
```

My pom :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <stormpath.version>1.1.1</stormpath.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.stormpath.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>stormpath-default-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${stormpath.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stormpath version 1.1.1 works with spring-booth 1.4.  I solved the problem by changing the spring-boot-starter-parent version to 1.4.1.

Comment: That's right. You need to be sure you are using the same Spring Boot version that the SDK is internally using.

Comment: Yep, that was a bug in Spring Boot 1.3 and fixed subsequently in 1.4

Comment: Adding the stormpath sdk doesn't change the spring version since the spring version is in the parent pom.  I was integrating it in an existing app built on 1.3, it was not a collision managed by maven.  It works well with 1.4.